# What is meant by this Zend Form Validator

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-validate

Hi there I have just gone through a code and saw a line of Zend validation. I am unable to understand what it means.

```
   $affiliateModel = new AffiliateUser();
   $metaData = $affiliateModel->info('metadata');
```

And here is my form element

```
  $first_name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('first_name');
  $first_name->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('StringLength', false, array(2, $metaData['first_name']['LENGTH']))
            ->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper', 'errors'));
```

I know what every line do but what this line will do

```
->addValidator('StringLength', false, array(2, $metaData['first_name']['LENGTH']))
```

Does any body will explain what this `validator` will do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`->addValidator('StringLength', false, array(2, $metaData['first_name']['LENGTH']));`

Will add a validator that will only consider a string valid if it's length falls in [2, x] where x is the `$metaData[...][...]` value.  (Internally, the form will create and configure a [`Zend_Validate_StringLength`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set.stringlength) instance.)

Comment: It means that if `metadata` returns 255, it will consider only string valid having length in between 2 to 255?

Comment: @AwaisQarni By the way, as cryptic as Zend stuff can end up being, I would use the explicit version of `array('min' => 2, 'max' => $metaData...);`